# Realm Auto Increment field example

Tags: android, realm

I need to add auto increment key field in `Realm` database in Android.
How can I do this?
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Relam` currently doesn't support auto_increment

see this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/469)

you can take work around like this

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
         // increment index
         Number num = realm.where(dbObj.class).max("id");
         int nextID;
         if(num == null) {
            nextID = 1;
         } else {
            nextID = num.intValue() + 1;
         }
         dbObj obj = realm.createObject(dbObj.class, nextID);
         // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Per cmelchior, "Auto-incremented keys simply do not work in a distributed setting, so it is not something we would want to provide support for in the Realm library itself." (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3875#issuecomment-265435130)

Answer (score 1):

The Java binding does not support primary keys yet, but it's on the roadmap and with high priority - see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/realm-java/6hFqdyoH67w
. As a workaround you can use this piece of code for generating keys:

```
int key;
try {
  key = realm.where(Child_pages.class).max("id").intValue() + 1;
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
 key = 0; // when there is no object in the database yet
}
```

I use [singleton factory for generating primary keys](https://gist.github.com/zacheusz/66c79df90b22a581d6f0) as a more generic solution with better performance (no need to query for `max("id")` every time).

There is a long discussion in Realm Git Hub if you need more context: [Document how to set an auto increment id?](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/469#issuecomment-197621062)

Comment: Hi, please, Can explain How to use the singleton? I just checked the gist but I don't know how to add it in my code.

Comment: 1st initialize it when app starts by calling `PrimaryKeyFactory.getInstance().initialize` then you can call `PrimaryKeyFactory.getInstance().nextKey` to get next key for given class

Comment: So can I add `PrimaryKeyFactory.getInstance().initialize` in my Application's onCreate just once, or I should add it on any given class I want use it?

Comment: yeah call `initialize` in `onCreate` and then use `PrimaryKeyFactory.getInstance().nextKey` in your logic

Comment: Sweet kotlin code:   val id = realm.where(MessageBean::class.java).max("id")?.toInt()?.plus(1) ?: 0