# How to set primary key auto increment in realm android

Tags: android, realm

I want to set primary key  auto increment for my table.

Here is my Class. I have set primary key but I want it to be auto increment primary key.

```
public class users extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private long icn;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private int phone;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getIcn() {
    return icn;
}

public void setIcn(long icn) {
    this.icn = icn;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realm Auto Increament field example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229226/realm-auto-increament-field-example)

Comment: I am looking for in built property in realm which will automatically increment like other database.

Comment: You won't find that because it doesn't exist. Mostly because it can be done in 6 lines without much effort, so it was never a high priority.

Comment: Realm is object database - it stores a graph of objects. Tables uses primary keys when indexing tables, there is no such a thing, Realm uses @PrimaryKey for indexing convenience

Comment: @AlexShutov well, primary keys are important to identify objects in order to update them later, and rather important for the newly released Realm Object Server's synchronization logic. But what you set as primary key is pretty much up to you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In a transaction, you can always reliably access the current maximum ID, based on which you can increment that and use it as the basis for the next ID.

```
 realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() { // must be in transaction for this to work
     @Override
     public void execute(Realm realm) {
         // increment index
         Number currentIdNum = realm.where(users.class).max(usersFields.ID);
         int nextId;
         if(currentIdNum == null) {
            nextId = 1;
         } else {
            nextId = currentIdNum.intValue() + 1;
         }
         users user = new users(); // unmanaged
         user.setId(nextId);
         //...
         realm.insertOrUpdate(user); // using insert API
     }
 }
```

Comment: BTW this is a bit trickier for Synchronized Realm's where it is typically better to use a random UUID instead. Or a RealmCounter when it will be supported.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how do you go about this when writing JSON directly into realm and you want to auto generate the primary key values? it would be nice if you could just ad a second annotation like RealmAutoGenerate

Comment: You probably can't do that automatically if you use the `createAllFromJson` and such methods.

Answer (score 12):

This is an old and already answered question, but I want to post another solution that I used.
You can do like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
// Realm transaction
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() { 
    @Override
     public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
         // Get the current max id in the users table
         Number maxId = bgRealm.where(users.class).max("id");
         // If there are no rows, currentId is null, so the next id must be 1
         // If currentId is not null, increment it by 1
         int nextId = (maxId == null) ? 1 : maxId.intValue() + 1;
         // User object created with the new Primary key
         users user = bgRealm.createObject(users.class, nextId);
         // Now you can update your object with your data. The object will be
         // automatically saved in the database when the execute method ends
         // ...
         // ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, @PrimaryKey is only indicates that field is a key. But you set it yourself when creating object and copying it to Realm. Consider using UUID.random(), ot increment it manually. (as in answer from comment): [Realm Auto Increament field example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229226/realm-auto-increament-field-example)

Comment: sorry, copied address of wrong tab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229226/realm-auto-increament-field-example

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin

My Interfaces

```
fun getRegistroIdentity(): Int
```

My Method

```
class RegistroOver(private val realm: Realm) : RegistroImplementation {

override fun getRegistroIdentity(): Int {
    val registro = realm.where(Registro::class.java).max("id")
    val result: Int
    result = if (registro == null) {
        1
    } else {
        registro.toInt() + 1
    }
    return result
}}
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

there is an example that make a sequence to implement auto increment of primary key `id`:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/505aaron/realm-migration-example/master/realm/sequencer.js

```
const sequencer = (realmInstance, schema, props) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let saved;

  try {
    realmInstance.write(() => {
      const obj = { ...props };

      if (typeof obj.id === 'undefined') {
        let seq = realmInstance.objects('Sequence').filtered(`name = "${schema}"`)[0];
        if (typeof seq === 'undefined') {
          seq = realmInstance.create('Sequence', { name: schema, value: 0 });
        }
        obj.id = seq.next();
      }
      saved = realmInstance.create(schema, obj, true);

      resolve({ ...saved });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
  }
});

export default sequencer;
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter answer can be something like this:

```
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("UserName");

    realm.beginTransaction();

    Number newId = realm.where(Person.class).max("id");
    person.setId(newId.intValue()+1);

    realm.copyToRealm(person);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

For react native

```
...
// this is the part where you are saving the newItem
realm.write(() => {
    // handle the id
    let id: any = realm.objects(this.Schema).max("id");
    newItem.id = id === undefined ? 1 : id++;
    realm.create(this.Schema, newItem);
    resolve(newItem);
});
```

Comment: that would have to be `++id` instead of `id++` no?

Answer (score -1):

i use this.

```
public static int nextID(Class table) {
        return instance.realm.where(table).findAll().max("id").intValue() + 1;
    }
```

So i i want to increment Class Person Id,

```
netID(Person.class);
```

Answer (score -3):

In my personal case, I set id as Unix time value. I know isn't increment but is unique

```
(int) System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

Comment: By Somehow if 2 records are inserted within a second then It will throw an error.

Comment: @MaazPatel mmm it's true. I will try to simulate your comment because in my application doesn't insert 2 items at the same time.

Comment: You shouldn't cast it to an int... Then it is a better option.

Comment: What if user changes the time back one hour or so?