# Why Realm don't support auto increment primary key?

Tags: realm

Is there some pros or cons to not implement that feature?

I know some [solutions](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/469) exist and that it's on there road maps  but are there any advantages behind that decision that we are not award of?

Comment: I think there are just more important things to do, considering you can set up autoincrement primary key with 6 lines of code

Comment: Yeah but, it's one of those things that usually comes out of the box, so I guess there must be something we're missing... Right?

Comment: What is the use case you're trying to solve? There are probably better alternatives than an auto-incrementing primary key.

Comment: @Michael ... use case? Any actually, just was wondering if there are something am missing with that design decision. Better alternatives...? Like what?

Comment: Like UUID? which doesn't depend on any IDs stored but it will be good enough to be unique for any common cases.

Comment: I didn't know heard about UUID til I tried to find a workaround about this "problem". And from what I've read, auto-increment seems to be safer since we're guaranteed to not have collision. So I'd rather call this a _solution/workaround_ than _better alternatives_ .Right?

Comment: It's really really easy to set up auto-increment primary keys though http://stackoverflow.com/a/40175572/2413303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a discussion on Github (see [realm/realm-cocoa#2591](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2591)) the Realm team said there are no plans for support any auto increment field, even if there's a few lines of code a developer can use for implementing this feature as you said.

From a Realm member in the discussion:

> We decided that we're not going to support this feature, because we would be unable to support it with simultaneous access from multiple processes.

So that's it.

Comment: That's kinda weird though. They do support multi-process locking during write transactions.

Comment: A more important issue is that auto-incremented keys do not work with offline sync across devices. Also Realm do not need keys for relationships, which is the primary reason they exist in SQL. The two other use cases are `sort after created` and `key for lookup`. If you want to sort based on when the object was created, having a `Date created = new Date()` will work. If it is to have a unique key for easy lookup `String id = UUID.random().toString();` will work.

Comment: Thank you, I think it'd be great if they let new comer (like me from the SQL world) know about this from the docs.