# Does Realm provide method to get next available generate primary key ( primaryKey )?

Tags: react-native, realm

When creating an object that has a primaryKey, does Realm provide a method to get / create **next available unique value** of a primary key? ( Auto-Increment )

```
const BookSchema = {
  name: 'Book',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id:    'int',    // primary key
    title: 'string',
    price: 'float'
  }
};
```

If not what are approaches to insuring value of primaryKey is unique?

Or should I make primary key a **uuid: { type: 'string' }**  ?

Using:

- react native 0.38.1

  - Android
  - iOS
- realm 0.15.0

Comment: I did not get your question please be more specific

Comment: If you're talking about auto-increment for primary key then it's not possible. Check this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289738/why-realm-dont-support-auto-increment-primary-key/40290165#40290165 So my guess is you'd better use UUIDs.

Comment: Yes auto-increment is what I meant.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

It's sad, but true.

Using uuid's for objects isn't as developer-friendly as a readable int. I recon it will impact performance as well.
So if you don't want to, I think the best option would be to get the maximum id from the collection itself:

```
const getMaxId = (collection) => {
    const maxId = Math.max.apply(null,collection.map((item) => item.id));
    return maxId ? maxId : 1;
};
```