# Data is not updated promptly after adding the information using Realm in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm, android-alertdialog, realm-mobile-platform

I have implement Realm database in my App. At first I want to show some prelod data. Till now I have only three data here. I have implement a dialog fragment which I used to add data in Realm database. I have read the official documentation of Realm. But the implementation of Adapter class is so complecated for me. Hence I have used RecyclerView.Adapter in my Adpater class. Now the problem I am facing that After adding the information the data is not showing promptly.The data is not upadted quickly. it is showing after clicking the add button again. I cannot identify what would be the problem in this case. Also I am happy if someone provide me suggessstion if the writing of this code is not good. Sorry for my bad English.

**Edited Adapter Class**
Here is my Adpater class

```
   public class PersonAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<PersonModel, PersonAdapter.PersonHolder> {

    private RealmResults<PersoneModel> realmResults;
    private List<PersonModel> personModels;
    private Context context;

    public interface PersonListListener {
        void addPerson(PersonModel personModel);
        void editPerson(PersonModel personModel);
    }

    public PersonAdapter(Context context,RealmResults<PersonModel> realmResults) {
        this.realmResults = realmResults;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public PersonHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       // inflate a new person view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.colleage_row_layout,parent,false);
        return new PersonHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // get the colleague
        final PersonModel person=realmResults.get(position);
        // cast the generic view holder to the specific one
        final PersonHolder holder = (PersonHolder) viewHolder;
        holder.name.setText(person.getName());
        holder.companye.setText(person.getCompany());
        holder.title.setText(person.getTitle());
        holder.cardView.setTag(position);
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //editDataInterface.editData(view,position);
                int pos = (int)view.getTag();
                Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailPerson.class);
                i.putExtra("name",person.getName());
                i.putExtra("company",person.getCompany());
                i.putExtra("title",person.getTitle());
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    // return the size of your data set (invoked by the layout manager)
    public int getItemCount() {
        return realmResults.size();
    }

    public class PersonHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public CardView cardView;
        public ImageView picture;
        public TextView  name;
        public TextView  company;
        public TextView  title;

        public ColleagueHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            company=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.company_name);
            title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_title);
            cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_user);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited Activity Calss** My Activity class is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PersonAdapter.PersonListListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PersonAdapter adapter;
private Realm personRealm;
private List<PersonModel> personObject;
private RealmResults<PersonModel> dataResult;
private static final String DIALOG_TAG = "EmployeeDialog";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);

    // Showing and Enabling clicks on the Home/Up button
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    personRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.person_recycler);

    setUpRecycler();

    if (!Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()) {
        setRealmData();
    }
    showAllPersons();
}
private void showAllPersons() {
    dataResult = personRealm.where(PersonModel.class).findAll();
    setAdapter(dataResult);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private void setAdapter(RealmResults<PersonModel> results) {
    adapter = new PersonAdapter(this, results);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
private void setUpRecycler() {
    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager since the cards are vertically scrollable
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

private void setRealmData(){

    List<MyColleagueModel> colleague = new ArrayList<>();
    MyColleagueModel model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(1 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name1");
    model.setCompany("Comapny1");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    colleague.add(model);

    model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(2 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name2");
    model.setCompany("Comapny2");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    colleague.add(model);

    model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(3 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name3");
    model.setCompany("Comapny3");
    model.setTitle("Title3");
    colleague.add(model);


    for (MyColleagueModel realmModel : colleague) {
            // Persist the colleague data
            colleagueRealm.beginTransaction();
            colleagueRealm.copyToRealm(realmModel);
            colleagueRealm.commitTransaction();
    }

    Prefs.with(this).setPreLoad(true);

 }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recycler_menu, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    //onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) add will open dialog box, which allows user to fill required data
    if (id == R.id.addColleague) {
        showAlertDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    EditColleagueFragment dialog = new EditColleagueFragment();
    //dialog.setPositiveButtonClickListener(this);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (colleagueRealm!= null)
        colleagueRealm.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}

/*@Override
public void onSaved() {
    dataResult = colleagueRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).findAll();
    setAdapter(dataResult);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}*/

@Override
public void addPerson(MyColleagueModel colleagueModel) {

}

@Override
public void editPerson(MyColleagueModel colleagueModel) {

   }
}
```

Comment: You need to call notifyDataSetChanged()/ notifyItemInserted() (depends on the situation) in order to see changes in the model immediately. Go through the official documentation.

Comment: I have read the documentation. But I am ver ynew in developing this. Could you plaese explain how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [realm-android-adapters](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
}
```

You need to do

```
public class MyColleaguesAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<MyColleagueModel, MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueHolder> {   
    public interface ColleagueListListener {
        void addPerson(MyColleagueModel colleagueModel);
        void editPerson(MyColleagueModel colleagueModel);
    }

    private final ColleagueListListener colleagueListListener;

    public MyColleaguesAdapter(ColleagueListListener colleagueListListener, RealmResults<MyColleagueModel> results) {
        super(results, true);
        this.colleagueListListener = colleagueListListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ColleagueHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ColleagueHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.colleage_row_layout,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ColleagueHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyColleagueModel myColleague = getData().get(position);
        holder.bind(myColleague);
    }

    public class ColleagueHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CardView cardView;
        public ImageView colleaguePicture;
        public TextView  colleagueName;
        public TextView  companyName;
        public TextView  jobTitle;

        private MyColleagueModel myColleague;

        private final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                  colleagueListListener.editPerson(myColleague);
             }
        }

        public ColleagueHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //colleaguePicture=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.drawable.profile_image);
            colleagueName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.colleague_name);
            companyName=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.company_name);
            jobTitle=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_title);
            cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_user);
          }
        }

        public void bind(MyColleagueModel myColleague) {
            this.myColleague = myColleague;
            holder.colleagueName.setText(myColleague.getName());
            holder.companyName.setText(myColleague.getCompany());
            holder.jobTitle.setText(myColleague.getTitle());
            holder.cardView.setTag(position);
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
 }
```

and

```
public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity implements MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueListListener {

    private Realm realm;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyColleaguesAdapter adapter;

    private static final String DIALOG_TAG = "EmployeeDialog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);

        // Showing and Enabling clicks on the Home/Up button
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(this, realm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("id"));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you plaese explain what would be the problem if I use RecyclerView.Adapter<MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueHolder> insted of  RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<MyColleagueModel, MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueHolder>. In this way I can also write data in realm. But  there might be one difference.

Comment: You are not adding `RealmChangeListener` to RealmResults to update adapter, so your data isn't added to UI when you add the data to Realm. The `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` does exactly that if you see its source code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I let you know just  after implementing this in my code.

Comment: I just tried your code, So far Adapter class is ok. And I do not need edit option now. I want to show detail Activity if user click on cardview. So Implemented add option to option menu. But I do not know how can I implement interface addPerson here to show all update data. you can see on my code I have creted adialog fragment to show add dilaog on item click

Comment: I am using latest version of Realm 3.5.0. shall I go back to previous version. because in the latest version I cannot use   super(results, true);

Comment: `how can I implement interface addPerson here to show all update data.` I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I have editen my Adpater and Activity. The problem is now using latest version of Realm. 3.5.0 and in this version it is showing error for super(results, true). I change the activity class also. but in my code I have implemented adding option to menu. In this case how can I link update the addPerson method here

Comment: You most likely just didn't delete your own `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` class which is clashing with `io.realm.RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.

Comment: Just now I delete. But  I got error like you should create one class for RealRecyclerView Adapter

Comment: You need to add `compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'` dependency.

Comment: yes I have compile with android-adapter 2.1.0. but truly I did not write any code to colleagueListListener. I just implement this method to main class, because I am using adding functionaliyt to main option menu. in this case, is it wise to implent this listener here. or shall i do it inside dilaog fragment

Comment: What is best parctise actually

Comment: https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example/blob/c249f2d687daacb05fccd53baef543c991134e66/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/realmbookexample/paths/books/BooksActivity.java#L142

Comment: thank you for this code. it is really helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:
Inside `EditColleagueFragment` create interface

```
public interface onSaveClickListener {
        void onSaved()
      }



private onSaveClickListener mSaveClickListener;

  public void setPositiveButtonClickListener(onSaveClickListener listener){
                mSaveClickListener=listener;
    }
```

Step 2: Inside MyColleaguesPage 
    `implement onSaveClickListener`

```
@Override
void onSaved(){
dataResult = colleagueRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).findAll();
setAdapter(dataResult);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    EditColleagueFragment dialog = new EditColleagueFragment();
    dialog.setPositiveButtonClickListener(this)
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);
    }
```

Step 3 :
     inside

```
void savePerson(){
    -----
    ---
    mSaveClickListener.onSaved();
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151260/discussion-on-answer-by-ram-prakash-bhat-data-is-not-updated-promptly-after-addi).