# Realm: Auto-Incrementing Primary Key

Tags: c#, .net, realm

I'm trying out Realm by implementing a simple financial book-keeping tool. I'm working with a schema that looks something like the following (inheriting from a sql based project)

[image: Example Schema]

Initially I setup classes for all of these tables with a `PrimaryKey` of type `long`. Then I learned that, at least as of 2015, realm [doesn't support auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229226/realm-auto-increament-field-example). In my own testing it appears to be true, as I get an exception saying `0` is a duplicate primary key.

Looking at the examples on the [getting started guide](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/) I tried to re-evaluate if I actually needed specific Id fields. For the most part it doesn't seem I particularly do aside from potential speed benefits of using a primary key in the database. But it seems reasonable to me to expect that Realm does this under the hood when I setup relations anyways. There was one exception though.

```
// TransactionLink.cs
using Realms;

namespace Finance.Models {
    public class TransactionLink : RealmObject {
        public Transaction Lhs { get; set; }
        public Transaction Rhs { get; set; }
    }
}

// Transaction.cs
using Realms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Finance.Models {
    public class Transaction : RealmObject {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        // ...

        [Ignored]
        public IQueryable<Transaction> LinkedTransactions {
            get {
                var lhs = Realm.All<TransactionLink>().Where(tl => tl.Lhs.Id == Id).Select(tl => tl.Rhs);
                var rhs = Realm.All<TransactionLink>().Where(tl => tl.Rhs.Id == Id).Select(tl => tl.Lhs);
                return lhs.Union(rhs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I considered perhaps having Transaction have a field `IList<Transaction>` but I didn't like the removed benefit of having one entry that adds it to both of them. Having to maintain separate copies of the data wasn't appealing to me. I considered instead of comparing the Id using the `Equals` function as I noticed `RealmObject` overloads it (something like `tl => tl.Rhs.Equals(this)`), but I wasn't sure how it would handle in queries (maybe I should try that after posting this question...but I'm a little ways from being able to test that)

Well, at this point (I could be wrong) it seems it was best for me to implement something auto-incrementing. So following off the example in the [afore-mentioned stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229226/realm-auto-increament-field-example) I came up with something.

```
// IPrimaryKeyId.cs
namespace Finance.Context {
    public interface IPrimaryKeyId {
        long Id { get; set; }
    }
}

// Database.cs
using Finance.Models;
using Realms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using static Finance.Context.Handle;

namespace Finance.Context {
    public class Database {
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        // Non-Static Interface: Provide access to all the tables in the database                                      |
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        private Realm Db { get; set; }
        public IQueryable<Bank>                  Banks                  { get { return Db.All<Bank>(); } }
        public IQueryable<Models.Transaction>    Transactions           { get { return Db.All<Models.Transaction>(); } }
        public IQueryable<TransactionLink>       TransactionLinks       { get { return Db.All<TransactionLink>(); } }
        // ...

        public void SetupExample() {
            AutoIncrement(new Bank { Name = "Cash" });
            var first = Banks.First();
            MessageBox.Show(first.Id.ToString() + ": " + first.Name);
        }

        public void AutoIncrement<T>(T obj) where T : RealmObject, IPrimaryKeyId {
            AutoIncrement(Db, obj);
        }

        public static void AutoIncrement<T>(Realm db, T obj) where T : RealmObject, IPrimaryKeyId {
            db.Write(() => {
                long id = db.All<T>().Max(el => el.Id);
                obj.Id = id + 1;
                db.Add(obj);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The [afore-mentioned guide](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/) says realm doesn't like inheritance in these classes but it seemed to run ok with this simple interface. The problem is that on the line that calls `Max()` it throws a `NotSupportedException`. So now I'm left with a few potential problems to solve, any one of which will get me moving forward.

1. Alternative to `Max()` for determining the max `Id`
2. Verifying the efficacy of using `Equals(this)` inside of a Linq query and ditching Ids all together
3. Another alternative I haven't considered

This is for me getting accustomed to realm, so as much as possible I want to do things "the realm way". Any other comments about how I can fit that style better are welcome.

## Responses to @Cristo

The line in question where the exception gets called is `long id = db.All<T>().Max(el => el.Id);` as you can see in the above code snippet. The exact text is `System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'Max' is not supported'`. The stack trace is

```
[External Code] 
Finance.exe!Finance.Context.Database.AutoIncrement.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 48 C#
[External Code] 
Finance.exe!Finance.Context.Database.AutoIncrement<Finance.Context.Handle>(Realms.Realm db, Finance.Context.Handle obj) Line 47 C#
Finance.exe!Finance.Context.Database.Create(string file) Line 74    C#
Finance.exe!Finance.MainWindow.Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 14    C#
[External Code]
```

Where line 47 corresponds to the `db.Write(` and 48 corresponds to the line with the call to `Max`

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/new "We monitor the `realm` tag." - So where are you?....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that on the line that calls Max() it throws a NotSupportedException

**Assuming** you have an int|long|... type as the primary key, you can use `Last()` on a transient query to obtain the last|max id value and manually increment it by one (since the Realm query is lazy loaded, only the last object is instanced to determine the current value of the primary key).

#### Example:

```
public class ItemModel : RealmObject
{
    public ItemModel() { }

    public ItemModel(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public static ItemModel Create()
    {
        ItemModel NewItemModel()
        {
            var q = Realm.GetInstance(Consts.realmDBName).All<ItemModel>();
            return new ItemModel(q.Any() ? q.Last().ID + 1 : 0);
        }

        if (Realm.GetInstance(Consts.realmDBName).IsInTransaction)
        {
            return NewItemModel();
        }
        // Use a pseudo transaction to ensure multi-process safety on obtaining the last record 
        using (var trans = Realm.GetInstance(Consts.realmDBName).BeginWrite())
        {
            return NewItemModel();
        }
    }

}
```

#### Usage:

```
var aRealmObject = instance.Add(ItemModel.Create(), false);
```

Comment: The `Create` function you put forward as an example would have to be copy pasted onto every class that inherits `RealmObject`, which is the reason I went towards implementing an interface. However the suggestion of `Last` I was able to bring into my solution and it appears to be working. I do wonder however if I will run into any problems down the road for reasons similar to the exception message I mentioned in comment to Cristo's answer: `IPrimaryKeyId is not in the limited set of classes for this Realm`. Thoughts?

Comment: @Assimilater You do not have to copy/paste the static Create method into each model, you could create a Class Factory that automatically sets the primary key (based upon the same logic, just in a generic fashion..., I only expose the RealmObject inheritance as a model-based interface, so it really does not matter to my design/architecture how is it done as long as the pri-key is set before it is added to your realm instance (as it can not be changed after...)). I'm not sure what Cristo was even imposing...(?).

Comment: It's just the error message that appeared when I tried to use `OrderByDescending`, I remember seeing things in the getting started guide that suggested that Realm didn't like classes that had inheritance

Comment: @Assimilater Ahh... ok. Yes, you can not have multiple levels of inheritance of a RealmObject... You definitely have design your models around that, is it a pain, sure, I tend to hide that from the consumer of any RealmObject by using interfaces,  but in the end you have to provide a concrete class that is stored in the realm instance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why 'Max' doesn't work there.  [Realm.All()](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/3.2.0/api/reference/Realms.Realm.html) returns an [IQueryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) which inherits [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), so you should be able to use [Max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__).  Are you sure that 'Max()' is throwing the NotSupportedException?  What's the value that's being returned by 'All'?  Can you post the exception message and stack trace?

An alternative to 'Max()' would be to order by descending and take element 0:

```
db.All<T>().OrderByDescending(el => el.Id).First();
```

If 'Max()' doesn't work, I wouldn't expect OrderByDescending to work either though.  You might have to loop over All and find the max id the old fashioned way.

Another alternative would be 'ToList', then try the above or sort.

A fugly hack alternative to the way you're using IPrimaryKeyId is to have each DB class inherit from an abstract base object which has a private static id incremented int the ctor...

```
public interface IPrimaryKeyId
{
    long Id { get; }
}

public abstract BankPrimaryKeyId : IPrimaryKeyId
{
    private static long _id;
    public long Id => _id;
    protected BankPrimaryKeyId()
    {
        _id++;
    }
}    

public class Bank : BankPrimaryKeyId
{
}
```

Comment: The static member would only work for as long as the program is running though. If the program is closed and opened again that tracking will be lost.

Comment: I updated my question with responses to your other inquires. Thanks for taking the time to respond

Comment: Attempting your OrderByDescending actually shed some light on the problem though: `System.NotSupportedException: 'The class IPrimaryKeyId is not in the limited set of classes for this Realm, so sorting by its properties is not allowed.'`